# Read and write in place not writing?

Tags: c

New to C and I'm trying to do a text replace in place. I thought r+ in fopen should allow me to read and write. I'm looking at every line in the file and if it begins with a / then I am prepending http://example.com to the beginning of the line. Example...line is /tree then that line becomes http://example.com/tree. The regex works fine. I can read the file fine but it is not writing. Any ideas why?

```
void
fix_relative (char *page)
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("file", "r+");

  char line[1000];
  regex_t re;
  regcomp (&re, "^/", REG_EXTENDED);

  while (fgets (line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
      if (regexec (&re, line, 0, NULL, 0) == 0) {
    fprintf (fp, "http://example.com%s\n", line);
      }
    }

  fclose (fp);
}
```

Comment: use ftell() and fseek() to more back.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in c? `sed -i 's|^/|http://example.com/|' file`

Comment: @Kevin - valid point but I think I should learn why this isn't working.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan So in the regexec if statement I would do a ftell to get the current position indicator then pass that to fseek to move the position to that location then do the fprintf like I did? I thought my position indicator is already at that location without doing any of that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way this can possibly work. You will run into a problem as soon as your new string is not *exactly* as long as the original string. In addition, since you are working in text mode, there may be additional artefacts because of newline/carriage return translation.

Instead, do the following:

- open the file "file" for reading only
- create a new temporary file for writing only
- read a line, modify if necessary, write to new file
- when done, delete "file" and rename your temp file.

Answer (score 2):

This may help you to understand your problem

fopen function

Purpose:
Opens a stream. The safer fopen_s function is also available.

Syntax:
FILE * fopen(const char *name, const char *mode);

Declared in:

The fopen function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by name, and associates a stream with it. The string may contain a full path (from the root), a relative path (from the current directory) or just a name.

The argument mode points to a string. If the string is one of the following, the file is open in the indicated mode.

- "r" Open text file for reading.
- "w" Truncate to zero length or create text file for writing.
- "a" Append; open or create text file for writing at end-of-file.
- "rb" Open binary file for reading.
- "wb" Truncate to zero length or create binary file for writing.
- "ab" Append; open or create binary file for writing at end-of-file.
- "r+" Open text file for update (reading and writing).
- "w+" Truncate to zero length or create text file for update.
- "a+" Append; open or create text file for update, writing at end-of-file.
- "rb+" Open binary file for update (reading and writing).
- "wb+" Truncate to zero length or create binary file for update.
- "ab+" Append; open or create binary file for update, writing at end-of-file.
- "r+b" Same as "rb+"
- "w+b" Same as "wb+"
- "a+b" Same as "ab+"

Opening a file with read mode ('r' as the first character in the mode argument) fails if the file does not exist or cannot be read.

Opening a file with append mode ('a' as the first character in the mode argument) causes all subsequent writes to the file to be forced to the then current end-of-file, regardless of intervening calls to the fseek function.

***When a file is opened with update mode ('+' as the second or third character in the mode argument), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the fflush function or to a file positioning function (fseek, fsetpos, or rewind), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.***

When opened, a stream is fully buffered if and only of it can be determined not to refer to an interactive device. The error and end-of-file indicators for the stream are cleared.

Returns:
A pointer to the object controlling the stream on success, otherwise a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may not be clear:  if you update lines in the file,  and your replacement text is not *precisely the same length* as what it is replacing, you will make a complete hash of the file:  you will be overwriting what comes after it.

So, if you have a file that contains the sentences:

```
   I love programming.
   I love life.
```

and you set the file position to the first sentence and replace "love" with "loathe", you will NOT get

```
   I loathe programming
   I love life
```

You will get

```
   I loathe programming love life
```

because you have now overwritten the line separator from the first sentence, and the "I" from the next sentence.

If you replace a string with a longer string, that will push every other character in the file forward.   To do that replacement, you'd have to read the entire file into memory, do your replacements, and then write the file back out to disk.

Comment: I just found this out! This is no fun.